# How we can create dataproc cluster using apache airflow API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I am new in Python and Airflow, I have created 4 tasks in my Python script using `pythonoperator`. First & second task retrieves the zip file from `GCP Bucket` then reading the data and another task is merging both file data. Now I need to create one more task which can be created `Dataproc Cluster`.

I have seen `Airflow API`, but I didn't get enough information and clues.
Is there any example which can be helpful?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

There is an operator called `DataprocClusterCreateOperator` that will create the Dataproc Cluster for you.

Check the documentation of the `DataprocClusterCreateOperator` at https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator/index.html#module-airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator

```py
from airflow.contrib.operators import dataproc_operator

create_dataproc_cluster = dataproc_operator.DataprocClusterCreateOperator(
    task_id='create_dataproc_cluster',
    # Give the cluster a unique name by appending the date scheduled.
    # See https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#default-variables
    cluster_name='hadoop-cluster',
    num_workers=2,
    zone='europe-west1-b',
    master_machine_type='n1-standard-1',
    worker_machine_type='n1-standard-1',
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: Hello @kaxil,Please have a look into this question and try to provide your inputs - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61774987/how-we-can-use-sftptogcsoperator-in-gcp-composer-enviornment1-10-6

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we need to use DataprocClusterCreateOperator. first we need to import dataproc_operatror,then we need to pass all the arguments with dag argument also, otherwise error will come

```
from airflow.contrib.operators import dataproc_operator

create_dataproc_cluster = dataproc_operator.DataprocClusterCreateOperator(
    task_id='create_dataproc_cluster',
    project_id='trim-karma-248213',
    cluster_name='airflow-cluster',
    num_workers=2,
    zone='europe-west1-c',
    master_machine_type='n1-standard-1',
    worker_machine_type='n1-standard-1',
    dag=dag)
```