# How we can use SFTPToGCSOperator in GCP composer enviornment(1.10.6)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer, airflow

Here I want to use SFTPToGCSOperator in composer enviornment(1.10.6) of GCP. I know there is a limitation because The operator present only in latest version of airflow not in composer latest version 1.10.6.

See the refrence -
https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/operator/gcp/sftp_to_gcs.html

I found the alternative of operator and I created a plugin class, But again I faced the issue for sftphook class, Now I am using older version of sftphook class.

see the below refrence -

from airflow.contrib.hooks.sftp_hook import SFTPHook
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/hooks/sftp_hook.html

I have created a plugin class, later It's import in my DAG script. It's working fine only when we are moveing one file, In that case we need to pass complete file path with extension.

Please refer below example(It's working fine in this scenrio)

```
DIR = "/test/sftp_dag_test/source_dir"
OBJECT_SRC_1 = "file.csv"

source_path=os.path.join(DIR, OBJECT_SRC_1),
```

Except this If we are using wildcard, I mean if we want to move all the files from directory I am getting error for get_tree_map method.

Please see below DAG code

```
import os

from airflow import models
from airflow.models import Variable
from PluginSFTPToGCSOperator import SFTPToGCSOperator
#from airflow.contrib.operators.sftp_to_gcs import SFTPToGCSOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {"start_date": days_ago(1)}

DIR_path = "/main_dir/sub_dir/"
BUCKET_SRC = "test-gcp-bucket"

with models.DAG(
    "dag_sftp_to_gcs", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None
) as dag:

    copy_sftp_to_gcs = SFTPToGCSOperator(
        task_id="t_sftp_to_gcs",
        sftp_conn_id="test_sftp_conn",
        gcp_conn_id="google_cloud_default",
        source_path=os.path.join(DIR_path, "*.gz"),
        destination_bucket=BUCKET_SRC,
    )

    copy_sftp_to_gcs
```

Here we are using wildcard * in DAG script, please see below plugin class.

```
import os
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from typing import Optional, Union

from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from airflow import AirflowException
from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcs_hook import GoogleCloudStorageHook
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.contrib.hooks.sftp_hook import SFTPHook
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults

WILDCARD = "*"

class SFTPToGCSOperator(BaseOperator):

    template_fields = ("source_path", "destination_path", "destination_bucket")

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
        self,
        source_path: str,
        destination_bucket: str = "destination_bucket",
        destination_path: Optional[str] = None,
        gcp_conn_id: str = "google_cloud_default",
        sftp_conn_id: str = "sftp_conn_plugin",
        delegate_to: Optional[str] = None,
        mime_type: str = "application/octet-stream",
        gzip: bool = False,
        move_object: bool = False,
        *args,
        **kwargs
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.source_path = source_path
        self.destination_path = self._set_destination_path(destination_path)
        print('destination_bucket : ',destination_bucket)
        self.destination_bucket = destination_bucket
        self.gcp_conn_id = gcp_conn_id
        self.mime_type = mime_type
        self.delegate_to = delegate_to
        self.gzip = gzip
        self.sftp_conn_id = sftp_conn_id
        self.move_object = move_object

    def execute(self, context):
        print("inside execute")
        gcs_hook = GoogleCloudStorageHook(
            google_cloud_storage_conn_id=self.gcp_conn_id, delegate_to=self.delegate_to
        )

        sftp_hook = SFTPHook(self.sftp_conn_id)

        if WILDCARD in self.source_path:
            total_wildcards = self.source_path.count(WILDCARD)
            if total_wildcards > 1:
                raise AirflowException(
                    "Only one wildcard '*' is allowed in source_path parameter. "
                    "Found {} in {}.".format(total_wildcards, self.source_path)
                )
            print('self.source_path : ',self.source_path)
            prefix, delimiter = self.source_path.split(WILDCARD, 1)
            print('prefix : ',prefix)
            base_path = os.path.dirname(prefix)
            print('base_path : ',base_path)
            files, _, _ = sftp_hook.get_tree_map(
                base_path, prefix=prefix, delimiter=delimiter
            )

            for file in files:
                destination_path = file.replace(base_path, self.destination_path, 1)
                self._copy_single_object(gcs_hook, sftp_hook, file, destination_path)

          else:
            destination_object = (
                self.destination_path
                if self.destination_path
                else self.source_path.rsplit("/", 1)[1]
            )
            self._copy_single_object(
                gcs_hook, sftp_hook, self.source_path, destination_object

            )

    def _copy_single_object(
        self,
        gcs_hook: GoogleCloudStorageHook,
        sftp_hook: SFTPHook,
        source_path: str,
        destination_object: str,
    ) -> None:
    """
    Helper function to copy single object.
    """
        self.log.info(
            "Executing copy of %s to gs://%s/%s",
            source_path,
            self.destination_bucket,
            destination_object,
        )

        with NamedTemporaryFile("w") as tmp:
            sftp_hook.retrieve_file(source_path, tmp.name)
            print('before upload self det object : ',self.destination_bucket)
            gcs_hook.upload(
                self.destination_bucket,
                destination_object,
                tmp.name,
                self.mime_type,
            )

        if self.move_object:
            self.log.info("Executing delete of %s", source_path)
            sftp_hook.delete_file(source_path)


    @staticmethod
    def _set_destination_path(path: Union[str, None]) -> str:
        if path is not None:
            return path.lstrip("/") if path.startswith("/") else path
        return ""


    @staticmethod
    def _set_bucket_name(name: str) -> str:
        bucket = name if not name.startswith("gs://") else name[5:]
        return bucket.strip("/")

class SFTPToGCSOperatorPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "SFTPToGCSOperatorPlugin"
    operators = [SFTPToGCSOperator]
```

So this plugin class I am importing in my DAG script and it's wotking fine when we are using file name, Because code is going inside else condition.

But when we are using wildcard we have cursor inside if condition and I am getting error for get_tree_map method.

see below error -

```
ERROR - 'SFTPHook' object has no attribute 'get_tree_map'
```

I found the reason of this error this method itself is not present in composer(airflow 1.10.6)- 
    https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/hooks/sftp_hook.html

This method is present in latest version of airflow
    https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/airflow/providers/sftp/hooks/sftp.html

Now What should I can try, Is there any alternative of this method or any alternative of this operator class.

Does anyone know if there is a solution for this?

Thanks in Advance.

Please ignore Typo or indentation error in stackoverflow. In my code there is no Indentation error.

Comment: Hi! Can you try to create another plugin with SFTPHook (https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/fc862a3edd010e65b9b3fe586855fe81807ee4e8/airflow/providers/sftp/hooks/sftp.py#L30)? And then you need to change "from airflow.contrib.hooks.sftp_hook import SFTPHook" in your SFTPToGCSOperator plugin file. What were your steps while creating the plugin, what this name "PluginSFTPToGCSOperator" in DAG specifies?

Comment: Hi @muscat, thanks for your response, My plugin class name is PluginSFTPToGCSOperator.py, As you said I have create a nre plugin file with new import But I am getting Error....   Broken plugin: [/home/airflow/gcs/plugins/PluginSFTPToGCSOperator.py] No module named 'airflow.providers'

Comment: I've added answer with working plugin. I hope you'll find it useful. It's all about copying the code from Airflow repository. I also found the solution for No module named 'airflow.providers' error.

Answer (score 1):

"providers" packages are only available from Airflow 2.0, which is not yet available in Cloud Composer (as I write this post, the latest available Airflow image is 1.10.14, released this morning).

BUT you can import backport packages which let you enjoy these new packages in earlier versions 1.10.*.

My requirements.txt:

```
apache-airflow-backport-providers-ssh==2020.10.29
apache-airflow-backport-providers-sftp==2020.10.29
pysftp>=0.2.9
paramiko>=2.6.0
sshtunnel<0.2,>=0.1.4
```

You can import PyPi packages directly in your Composer environment from the console.

With these dependencies, I could use the newest `airflow.providers.ssh.operators.ssh.SSHOperator` (formerly `airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator.SSHOperator`) and the new `airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_sftp.GCSToSFTPOperator` (which had no equivalent in `contrib` operators).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

To use `SFTPToGCSOperator` in Google Cloud Composer on Airflow version 1.10.6 we need to create a plugin and somehow "hack" Airflow by copying operator/hook codes into one file to enable `SFTPToGCSOperator` use code from Airflow 1.10.10 version.

The latest Airflow version has a new `airflow.providers` directory, which does not exist in earlier versions. This is why you saw following error: `No module named airflow.providers`. All the changes I made are described here:

I prepared working plugin, which you can download [here](https://wtools.io/paste-code/b1g8). Before using it, we have to install following PyPI libraries on the Cloud Composer environment: `pysftp`, `paramiko`, `sshtunnel`.

1. I copied full `SFTPToGCSOperator` [code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/sftp_to_gcs.py), which starts in 792nd line. You can see that this operator uses `GCSHook`:

   `from airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.gcs import GCSHook`

   which also need to be copied to the plugin - starts in 193rd line.
2. Then, `GCSHook` inherits from `GoogleBaseHook` class, which we can change for `GoogleCloudBaseHook` accessible in Airflow 1.10.6 version, and import it:

   `from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcp_api_base_hook import GoogleCloudBaseHook`
3. Finally, there is a need to import `SFTPHook` [code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/fc862a3edd010e65b9b3fe586855fe81807ee4e8/airflow/providers/sftp/hooks/sftp.py#L30) into the plugin - starts in 39th line, which inherits from `SSHHook` class, we can use one from Airflow 1.10.6 version by changing import statement:

   `from airflow.contrib.hooks.ssh_hook import SSHHook`
4. At the end of file, you can find the definition of the plugin:

```
class SFTPToGCSOperatorPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "SFTPToGCSOperatorPlugin"
    operators = [SFTPToGCSOperator]
```

Plugin creation is needed, as an Airflow built-in operator is not currently available in Airflow 1.10.6 version (the latest in Cloud Composer). You can keep an eye on Cloud Composer [version lists](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions) in order to see when the newest version of Airflow will be available to use.

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Comment: Hello @muscat, Thanks for your valuable inputs. I tried with your plugin code. But still facing issue - 'GCSHook' object has no attribute 'client_info

Comment: @BhageshArora, where do you define` client_info`?

Comment: Hello @ Alexandre Moraes,In this plugin code -  https://wtools.io/paste-code/b1g8 you can see line no. 277

Comment: @BhageshArora I haven't experienced the error you mentioned. Anyway I tried to change the code by adding additional code, and it works for me as well: https://wtools.io/paste-code/b1nT please, check it and let me know if that one works for you.

Comment: Hello @muscat, I don't know what is the issue. I am using your plugin code. now getting ERROR -  __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'source'. can you please check what is the reason and please share DAG script also.

Comment: It's same as yours. You can try to restart the scheduler by adding additional PyPi package to your Composer environment.